# Can there be a batch file to block websites?

Tags: windows, batch-file

A common method to block websites is to go this directory.
C->System32–>drivers–>etc and add the exceptions to the 'hosts' file.
But anybody can re-edit the file and remove the exceptions.

So..is there some kind of batch programming to block certain websites ?

Comment: That's the result of running a lax security policy where there are no passwords and no differentiation between administrators and normal users who shouldn't be able to edit such files...

Comment: NTFS permissions?  -Edit, this is more a security question demonstrated by the lack of code provided by the question author.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for this.

1. Change admin rights and set up yourself as the supervisor and everyone else as something else and lock edit permissions.
2. Write a bat file that opens both the internet and a second bat file that reads the website to the host file. If you do this every single time they start the web browser they will add the website back to the blocked list in the background forcing them to exit if they want to change it and if that happens they will reblock the website when they open the web browser again. Effective and out of some peoples abilities bypass. 
   Example can be found here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/launch-multiple-programs-single-shortcut-using-batch-file/
3. Similar to the method above add that bat file to launch when someone access's the hosts file with a timeout function to rewrite the hosts file after  some amount of time...
4. Password protecting the system 32 folder but this could prove problematic for a plethora of reasons.